# Remove rows from search expression solr

Tags: select, solr, nosql, expression, solrj

I'm trying to search for the items which's attribute matches the given function below in my large dataset, but I'm facing a problem here.

The row parameter only selects first 300 objects and the function then filters the matching results, but I'm trying to search the whole index, not only just first few, how can I rewrite this to achieve it?

```
having(
select(search(myIndex,q="*:*",  fl="*", rows=300),
id,
       dotProduct(ATTRIBUTE, array(4,5,2)) as prod,
       l1norm(array(1,2,3)) as a,
       l1norm(ATTRIBUTE) as b,
       div(prod, add(a, sub(b, prod))) as c
), and(gteq(c,  5), lteq(c, 8)))
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to increase the number of rows to cover the number of entries in the index.

However if this number is huge, you should probably use the [`/export`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/exporting-result-sets.html) request handler instead of a regular select-like handler.

> The `/export` request handler allows a fully sorted result set to be
> streamed out of Solr using a special rank query parser and
> response writer. These have been specifically designed to work together to handle scenarios that involve sorting and exporting millions of records.

Depending on your needs, you could also do multiple queries playing with paginated results using both parameter `start` and `rows`, or if the number of entries is not known by the client code, use [`cursorMark`](https://solr.apache.org/guide/solr/latest/query-guide/pagination-of-results.html#using-cursors).

Comment: I've added export but now I'm getting different results, I've edited qt param like so search(myIndex,q="*:*",  fl="*", qt="/export", sort="id asc")

Comment: And here I need to specify fl one by one here?

Comment: fl = "id, attribute" , this attribute type is pdouble and the results have different value than the original

Comment: The field list wildcard `fl="*"` is not supported by the /export handler, so yes you must be specific about which fields to return, the query must also include the `sort` parameter. You might also need to specify the default parameters defined in the previously-used request handler. And, I should have mentioned, all the fields being sorted and exported must have docValues set to true. Check both the field definitions and the request satisfy all the conditions. To get more insight, you can still compare the parsed query when used with one request handler vs the other.

Comment: Yeah I figured it out, but for example if I have my attribule: [0.0,1.0,0.0,0.0,1.0] after search query I get this attribute sorted like so [0.0,0.0,0.0,1.0,1.0] any idea on how to avoid this?

Comment: If this is the content of a multivalued pdouble field, no I don't know what could cause this, except maybe different response writers config. Do you have a difference with /stream vs /export requests ? You can check/modify the config of implicit request handlers using the Config API.